# Save PHPMailer debug to database not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a php script that sends emails using PHPMailer see below:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $debug = NULL;
    $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
        $GLOBALS['debug'] .= "$level: $str\n";
    };
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'xxxxxxx';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxx';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('xx-xx@xx.com', 'xxx');
    $mail->addAddress('xx-xx@xx.com');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'xx';
    $email_content = '<p>test</p>';
    $mail->Body = $email_content;
    $mail->send();
    fncSaveLog($debug);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fncSaveLog($mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

the fncSaveLog is a function that saves debug info to database but I see always NULL for debug in my DB, it seems the output is never caught. Any idea how to fix this please?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to post the code to fncSaveLog. Looks like that's where the error is.

Comment: The function to save data to db has no errors, it says cannot save NULL as value because the field for debug I have does not allow NULL

Comment: Ah, I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setting `NULL` to save into the db. Try the below instead:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {

    $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
        $GLOBALS['debug'] .= "$level: $str\n";
    };
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'xxxxxxx';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxx';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('xx-xx@xx.com', 'xxx');
    $mail->addAddress('xx-xx@xx.com');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'xx';
    $email_content = '<p>test</p>';
    $mail->Body = $email_content;
    $mail->send();
    $debug = $GLOBALS['debug'];
    fncSaveLog($debug);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fncSaveLog($mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

Comment: If I do as you are suggesting I get a new error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Comment: Try now with the updated the code, the value is now being fetch from your `$GLOBALS` array

Comment: is it $GLOBALS or $_GLOBALS ?

Comment: It is `$GLOBALS`

Comment: You may find there is additional info about any error in `$e->getMessage()` as well as in `$mail->ErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

To throw an exception in Php you have to use

```
throw new Exception('Your exception message');
```

Then your catch statement will show you your error message,
use this to look for errors.

Comment: There is no error message, I'm saying my debug variable has NULL as value